# Import Eclipse project workspace to Apache tomcat folder

Tags: java, eclipse, apache

I have created a simple Login Page using Eclipse and have tested and it works perfectly. I have copied the folder of the Project which I called **ABC** from my eclipse workspace to

`(the apache tomcat folder)/webapps`

I tried running it by typing

```
localhost:8080/ABC
```

but it produce me with the Error 404 Page.

This is my `web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" >   

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Welcome</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Welcome</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Welcome</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Welcome</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I have also attached images of file path

[ABC folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtrDK.png)

[ABC/WebContent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJSXd.png)

Comment: can you specify more details, e.g. is login page under default package?

Comment: @shyampatil Yes it is under default package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `Export` the `Dynamic Web Project` into a `.war` and deploy it into the Tomcat Webapps folder and restart the server.

Here are a few steps to help you:

[image: Click on Export>WAR]

[image: Select the Tomcat Webapps folder]

Then restart the server.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mine explaining why I have to convert to .war ?

Comment: We convert a dynamic web project to a .war file in order to deploy the Web Application into the server, so that the server can start accepting the request and send out the responses to and fro the web applicaton. The process of Deployment broadly means that the web application and its supporting components like resources and databases is getting installed in the server context. This installation is much more than simply copy-pasting the Web App Project Directory in the WebApps folder of the server. This link is helpful-  http://blog.xebia.com/so-what-is-a-deployment-really/